# Populating Drop down on the basis of User Group

Tags: visual-studio, event-handlers, site-column, dropdown, fast-for-sharepoint

I am developing the SharePoint Portal in 2010 where i will be using a Dropdown with values in it. These Values will depend on the group to which the user belongs.

For Eg.

If Drop Values are A, B , C, D, E

and there is a Group XYZ

If User A logs in & he belongs to Group XYZ the Drop down should show: A B E

Else the drop down should show : C, D

Anybody having an idea on how to do it. Please Share it.

Thanks Kishan Srivastava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1: Lookup list, if for entry into list**
If you can make an extra group ZYX which contains everybody except the people in XYZ then you can make the following:

1. Create a list with the choices A,B,C,D,E
2. On each item break inheritance and assign view right to groups XYZ and ZYX
3. Make your dropdown a lookup into the list

**Option 2: Audiences, if webparts on page**
Create two audiences one for people in group XYZ and one for others
Insert two webparts one for the first audience and one for the second with different configuration

**Option 3: Search Based**

1. Make a list an entry that only can be seen by group XYZ
2. Insert a search web part looking for the entry.
3. Change the XSLT to show A,B,E as result and C, D if no result

**Option 4: Code**

Comment: Thanks Per ... That was a great help..!!
I Have done using Option 1...!!
Can u give me more details on Option 4. How should i start with..!! Should i go for creating Site Coulmns or Event Receivers..??
I am trying with Option 2 but how could i change the item values , that i don't know...!!
Much Thanks Again Per

Comment: The reason for putting 4 options in is that your requirements a vague about how you'd use the dropdown. But if it's for adding values to a listitem, then Option 1 is the only good one. Option 4 would be possible using javascript on the form page

Comment: Per...!! If we want to disabled the selected drop down option after their Selection..!! Do you have any idea how to proceed with it..??
Thanks In Advance..!!

Comment: It's beginning to sound as if javascript on the form page using Client Object model is the best solution, but it's a bit hard to say without knowing what your requirements are and what has been implemented. Maybe you should create a new question with more information about what you need and add a like to it here.

Comment: I have posted the question in brief. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/33467/7689. 
Please have a look.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Lookup column. Set the permissions as appropriate on the list providing the values.

Comment: Thanks Paul..!! I have done it using the Lookup column...!!